# Apollo GraphQL: Change default Header INSIDE React Child Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to change the default header of my Apollo Graph QL Client **INSIDE** a react component and I simply cant manage to find anything in the docs. So in my index.js I create and link my client as described and add a JWT Token header. But what if I want to change the headers inside my React Component. For example, I want to replace the Token on reauthenticate.

In Axios you can simply do something with this.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = 'foo bar';
```

How can I do something like that with React Apollo? Here is he important part of my index.js

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://somesecureapi',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
return {
    headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
}
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

I tried to export the client and then import it to the component create a new Link and changethe old one but this didn't work.

There must be some easier way for this. Any suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`createHttpLink` accept `fetch` options, in which you can custom how you want your `fetch` to behave. A simple implementation could look like this:

```
import { ApolloProvider, graphql } from "react-apollo";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

const customFetch = (uri, options) => {
  return fetch(uri, {
    ...options,
    headers: {
      ...options.headers,
      "x-custom-header": "custom value"
    }
  });
};

const fetchLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "https://graphql-pokemon.now.sh",
  fetch: customFetch
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([fetchLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

As you can see in `customFetch`, I added `x-custom-header` with `"custom value"`. This will be applied to all query that uses this client. But, I am also spreading `options.headers` for the `fetch` options, so any headers that come will be passed through.

In our component, we can pass extra headers like this:

```
const WrappedPokemon = graphql(PokemonQuery, {
  options: {
    context: { headers: { "x-another-custom-header": "another custom value" } }
  },
  props: ({ data }) => ({
    loading: data.loading,
    pokemon: data.pokemon || {}
  })
})(Pokemon);
```

This extra header will only exist for this query only, unlike the one above.

I have made a simple implementation in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo7wxw1plz) to help you understand the implementation.

The result looks like this:
[image: The custom headers are getting passed through, yay!]